# how to navigate to error page(404 or 500) of a respective site

Tags: aem, dispatcher

ErrorDocument 404 ${error_doc}
Define error_doc /**sitename**/page-not-found.html

example:
If the IN site is clicked then the error page should go to
Define error_doc /IN/page-not-found.html

If the OUT site is clicked then the error page should go to
Define error_doc /OUT/page-not-found.html

So here the error page redirection should be dynamic as per the site it is called.